# An error occured while executing doInBackground() when I submit user input to the server

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm a beginner. I'm currently creating an app having connection between users and my server. For example, the user inputs some info and click the button then all the info will save in my server DB table. Howerver, after inputting the info and click the button, the app crushes. the logcat and java class is as below:

logcat

```
06-11 17:15:41.825  12946-12990/com.example.abc.androidhive W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=10: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa62bb288)
06-11 17:15:41.825  12946-12990/com.example.abc.androidhive E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
 at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
.
.
.
.
.
.
06-11 17:20:48.157  15150-15150/com.example.chongcng2.androidhive E/WindowManager﹕ Activity com.example.chongcng2.androidhive.NewJobActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@535a6b7c that was originally added here
android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.chongcng2.androidhive.NewJobActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@535a6b7c that was originally added here
```

NewJobActivity

```
public class NewJobActivity extends Activity {

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
EditText inputName;
EditText inputPrice;
EditText inputDesc;
EditText inputResponsibility;
EditText inputCompany;
EditText inputContact;

// url to create new product
private static String url_create_product = "http:/175.159.211.84/android_connect_server/create_job.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.server_add_job);

    // Edit Text
    inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
    inputPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
    inputDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);
    inputResponsibility = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputResponsibility);
    inputCompany = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputCompany);
    inputContact = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputContact);

    // Create button
    Button btnCreateProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreateProduct);

    // button click event
    btnCreateProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // creating new product in background thread
            new CreateNewProduct().execute();
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Create new product
 * */
class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewJobActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Creating Job..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Creating product
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        String post = inputName.getText().toString();
        String location = inputPrice.getText().toString();
        String salary = inputDesc.getText().toString();
        String responsibility = inputResponsibility.getText().toString();
        String company = inputCompany.getText().toString();
        String contact = inputContact.getText().toString();

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("post", post));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("location", location));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("salary", salary));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("responsibility", responsibility));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("company", company));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("contact", contact));

        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                "POST", params);

        // check log cat fro response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        // check for success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully created product
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllJobsActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // closing this screen
                finish();
            } else {
                // failed to create product
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
}
```

Could anyone help ? Thanks in advance !

logcat 2

```
06-12 04:33:52.964  12196-12196/com.example.chongcng2.androidhive W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa626c288)
06-12 04:33:52.964  12196-12196/com.example.chongcng2.androidhive E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
        at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
        at com.example.chongcng2.androidhive.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:51)
        at com.example.chongcng2.androidhive.NewJobActivity$CreateNewProduct.onPostExecute(NewJobActivity.java:121)
        at com.example.chongcng2.androidhive.NewJobActivity$CreateNewProduct.onPostExecute(NewJobActivity.java:74)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

NewJobActivity.java 2

```
public class NewJobActivity extends Activity {

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
EditText inputName;
EditText inputPrice;
EditText inputDesc;
EditText inputResponsibility;
EditText inputCompany;
EditText inputContact;
int success;
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

// url to create new product
private static String url_create_product = "http://192.168.0.103/android_connect_server/create_job.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.server_add_job);

    // Edit Text
    inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
    inputPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
    inputDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);
    inputResponsibility = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputResponsibility);
    inputCompany = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputCompany);
    inputContact = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputContact);

    // Create button
    Button btnCreateProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreateProduct);

    // button click event
    btnCreateProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // creating new product in background thread
            new CreateNewProduct().execute();
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Create new product
 * */
class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewJobActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Creating Job..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Creating product
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        String post = inputName.getText().toString();
        String location = inputPrice.getText().toString();
        String salary = inputDesc.getText().toString();
        String responsibility = inputResponsibility.getText().toString();
        String company = inputCompany.getText().toString();
        String contact = inputContact.getText().toString();

        // Building Parameters

        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("post", post));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("location", location));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("salary", salary));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("responsibility", responsibility));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("company", company));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("contact", contact));

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();

        try {
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                    "POST", params);

            // check log cat fro response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());
             success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully created product
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllJobsActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                finish();
            } else {
                // failed to create product
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: If your 'succes' variable is 1 do you launch a new Activity right?
So you are forgiving dismiss the progress dialog because its dissmis(); is called until onPostExcecute(), call a dissmis() before launching a new Activity.

Comment: yes. after successfully submited the user input to my server, a new activity will be shown to display the info that the user has just typed. But what do you mean ? I'm sorry that I can't fully understand what you mean. Could you state more clearly or would you mind telling me which part of the code I should revise ? Thank you :)

Comment: It appears that you cut out the important parts of the stacktrace. Please post the entire thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you launch your AssyncTask it will show a progressDialog on screen

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewJobActivity.this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Creating Job..");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(true);
    pDialog.show();
}
```

If you launch a new activity from inside an AssyncTask withoud 'Dismissing' the progress dialog before, you will have a new Activity, new Context and new View in your screen, but your AssyncTask are not finalized yet, and when it reach the

```
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    // dismiss the dialog once done
    pDialog.dismiss();
}
```

it will try to dissmis a window that is not in your view anymore.

```
Activity com.example.chongcng2.androidhive.NewJobActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@535a6b7c that was originally added here
android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.chongcng2.androidhive.NewJobActivity has leaked window
```

Is the best way i can explain it XD I used to see this errors on my code until i realized what was wrong. I hope it help you.

**Edit 1**

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

     pDialog.dismiss();

     try {

         if (success == 1) {
             // successfully created product
             Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllJobsActivity.class);
             startActivity(i);

             // closing this screen
             finish();
         } else {
             // failed to create product
         }
     } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }

}
```

**Edit 2:**
Initialize

```
int success;
```

outsuide any method as you declared pDialog and your TextView,do not initialize it direclty inside the 'try'

```
int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
```

i would ask you or initialize the variable as 0 and that is all

Comment: Very good explanation of what causes the problem. Can you also suggest a solution?

Comment: launch the new activity until onPostExcecute()

Comment: You can edit your answer to include that information...and format the code.

Comment: Thank you ! do you mean I should move the code starting from "try {

         if (success == 1) { " from doInBackground () to onPostExecute() ? If so, I try it. But it said " cannot resolve symbol 'success' ", becasue int success is declared inside doInBackground ().  All the variables are inter related inside doInBackground (), i.e.: params, JSONObject json, int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS); So I don't have idea to handle it. That' means I don't have idea to revise the final correct doInBackground () and onPostExecute () that it should look like :(

Comment: @CalvinNg First, you need to make `success` a member variable rather than a local variable in `doInBackground()`. Also, you shouldn't call `finish()` on the current activity.

Comment: Please explain the changes and how they fix the problem. You also need to explain that `success` will now need to be a member variable.

Comment: I just revise the code and it is no longer : error occured while executing doInBackground() . It triggers other problem. Would you mind viewing the logcat2 and NewJobActivity.java2 I have just uploaded to see whether I misunderstand what you have told me or what mistake I have make and help me revise the code ? Thank you very much

Comment: Anyway, I just added if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) { StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build(); StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); } Then, it works ! I'd appreciate your help :) thank you @UrielUVD